# Reverse query via foreign key and many to many field in Django

Tags: python, django

What query can I use to return all the Organisation objects that are members of a certain `membership_id` value?

e.g. return all Organisation objects that have a `membership_id = 101`

```
class Organisations(model)
    id = models.CharField()
    memberships = models.ManyToManyField("self", through="Memberships")

class Memberships(model)
    membership_id = models.IntegerField()
    organisation_id = models.ForeignKey(Organisations, related_name="orgs",)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
Organisations.objects.filter(orgs__membership_id=101)
```

Comment: Thanks Red, I just updated my question with a 2nd field for Organisations ('memberships' many to many field). Unfortunately when I try the above I get the error: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'memberships_set' into field. Choices are: id, memberships

Comment: @TomsCode OK I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks Red, the only problem now is that I get FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: membership_id. Its only allowing me to input fields in Organisations.

Comment: @TomsCode Try my new answer

Comment: I'm sure we're close but I now get: FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: Memberships

Comment: I added a related name field onto the questions as referencing that seemed to work for me